# How to find chromatic number of graph in R?

Tags: r, igraph, graph-coloring

I have the adjacency matrix of the graph (graph theory). First of all, I want to get the chromatic number of this graph (the smallest number of colors needed to color the vertices of a graph so that no two adjacent vertices share the same color). Then I want to get colors (like groups: from 1 to 4 maximum) of the vertices. Is it possible to get it in R using the igraph package? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @G5W This is absolutely not true. IGraph/M, igraph's Mathematica interface, [contains a very competitive method for computing the chromatic number](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGDocumentation/#graph-colouring).  There are several other packages, such as Sage or Maple, that have such functionality.  Some day I'll port over the implementation I wrote for IGraph/M to igraph's C core, to make it available in other interfaces, such as R. It's not a trivial amount of work though.

Comment: Basically all competitive implementations make use either of a SAT solver or an ILP solver. I used the former for IGraph/M.

Comment: igraph package v.1.3 include the vertex_greedy_coloring() function

Answer (score 0):

You can use the greedy_vertex_coloring() function to estimate the chromatic number.

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(44)
n = 8
m <- t(matrix(c(
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,
1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,
0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,
0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,
0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0),ncol=n))
g1 <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(m, weighted=TRUE, mode="directed")
ch_number <- max(greedy_vertex_coloring(g1))
```